# After Saving HTML file, Javascript does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

**Hi, Folks!** My goal is create HTML file without external Javascript.

Everything works in https://jsfiddle.net. But, when I open the HTML file the search script is no longer available.

What should I fix on the below code?

Thanks for any help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <title>Search Zip Code</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var filter = document.getElementById('zipcode');
    var JSONtbl = [
      {"zipcode":"01702","address":"334 CONCORD ST","County":"MIDDLESEX"},
      {"zipcode":"02482","address":"27 Atwood St","County":"NORFOLK"},
      {"zipcode":"02459","address":"189 Cypress St","County":"MIDDLESEX"}
          ];
    filter.onkeyup = function() {
        var zipcodeToSearch = filter.value;
        var n = zipcodeToSearch.length;
        if (n != 5) {
         document.getElementById("address").value = "";
         document.getElementById("County").value = "";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < JSONtbl.length; i++) {
             if (JSONtbl[i].zipcode == zipcodeToSearch) {
              document.getElementById("address").value = JSONtbl[i].address;
              document.getElementById("County").value = JSONtbl[i].County;
                 }
            }
            
        }
    };
    });
    //--><!]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form method="post">
    <div><input type="text" id="zipcode"/></div>
    <div><input type="text" id="address" disabled="disabled"></div>
    <div><input type="text" id="County" disabled="disabled"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your page does not include a `<script>` tag to import jQuery.

Comment: Also that CDATA thing is completely unnecessary here in 2016.

Comment: In your fiddle the jQuery is probably being included *before* the `$(document).ready`. In your document, its being included *after*, so `$` its not declared. Check your Console to check for js errors

Comment: Oh oops I didn't scroll down. But yes the jQuery import needs to be before it's used.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Headache is gone. You are great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include jQuery file before you use it.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Search Zip Code</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    </style>

    <!-- === HERE === -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- === HERE === -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var filter = document.getElementById('zipcode');
    var JSONtbl = [
            {"zipcode":"01702","address":"334 CONCORD ST","County":"MIDDLESEX"},
            {"zipcode":"02482","address":"27 Atwood St","County":"NORFOLK"},
            {"zipcode":"02459","address":"189 Cypress St","County":"MIDDLESEX"}
             ];
    filter.onkeyup = function() {
        var zipcodeToSearch = filter.value;
        var n = zipcodeToSearch.length;
        if (n != 5) {
            document.getElementById("address").value = "";
            document.getElementById("County").value = "";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < JSONtbl.length; i++) {
                if (JSONtbl[i].zipcode == zipcodeToSearch) {
                    document.getElementById("address").value = JSONtbl[i].address;
                    document.getElementById("County").value = JSONtbl[i].County;
                 }
            }

        }
    };
    });
    //--><!]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <div><input type="text" id="zipcode"/></div>
    <div><input type="text" id="address" disabled="disabled"></div>
    <div><input type="text" id="County" disabled="disabled"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have included Jquery after your js code, which is wrong jQuery must be loaded before any other code related to jQuery and cdata is irrelevant here thats not required anymore
https://jsbin.com/lubowovani/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Search Zip Code</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        padding: 2px 5px;
    }
    </style>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var filter = document.getElementById('zipcode');
    var JSONtbl = [
            {"zipcode":"01702","address":"334 CONCORD ST","County":"MIDDLESEX"},
            {"zipcode":"02482","address":"27 Atwood St","County":"NORFOLK"},
            {"zipcode":"02459","address":"189 Cypress St","County":"MIDDLESEX"}
             ];
    filter.onkeyup = function() {
        var zipcodeToSearch = filter.value;
        var n = zipcodeToSearch.length;
        if (n != 5) {
            document.getElementById("address").value = "";
            document.getElementById("County").value = "";
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < JSONtbl.length; i++) {
                if (JSONtbl[i].zipcode == zipcodeToSearch) {
                    document.getElementById("address").value = JSONtbl[i].address;
                    document.getElementById("County").value = JSONtbl[i].County;
                 }
            }

        }
    };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <form method="post">
    <div><input type="text" id="zipcode"/></div>
    <div><input type="text" id="address" disabled="disabled"></div>
    <div><input type="text" id="County" disabled="disabled"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in your `head` is running before you import jQuery (which you do in the body). That code utilizes jQuery, so it will not be able to find jQuery when it tries to use it (since it's not loaded yet).

Move your jQuery script tag to the head above the code that needs it.

For future reference simple errors like this can be solved easily by using the dev tools of most browsers. For example, in chrome the console is showing `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`, which can easily be interpreted as jQuery not being present for a script that is trying to use it. You can open them up by hitting `F12`.